# Trouble Updating Excel Cell Formulas with openpyxl in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am currently facing an issue while working on a Python script that aims to modify links in Excel cells containing formulas. The goal is to adjust the links to conform to a new pattern because the referenced locations of the workbooks have been changed. I've been attempting to achieve this using openpyxl, but unfortunately, I'm encountering difficulties in getting the program to function correctly. I have constructed a framework for the script's execution, which is presently being tested with a single referenced workbook. The code below shows a step in which I am trying to retrieve a list of existing data sources in the workbook.

The code:

```
import openpyxl

# function to get existing data sources in a workbook
def get_existing_data_sources(file_path):
    data_sources = set()

    try:
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

        for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
            sheet = workbook[sheet_name]

            for row in sheet.iter_rows():
                for cell in row:
                    if cell.hyperlink:
                        data_sources.add(cell.hyperlink.target)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while extracting data sources: {str(e)}")

    return data_sources

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Path to the workbook
    excel_file_path = '<EXAMPLE PATH>'

    existing_data_sources = get_existing_data_sources(excel_file_path)
    if not existing_data_sources:
        print("No data source links found in the workbook.")
```

I've encountered an issue where cells containing links in the formulas are replaced with brackets and numbers (e.g., [1]) when extracted into Python. This means I am unable to retrieve the old URL link to the workbook the cell was previously referencing. Additionally, when utilizing the .hyperlink property, it returns a None value, further complicating the matter. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to address this issue.

Example cell error:

```
# cell.value returns
=[1]Sheet1!A1
```

```
# cell.hyperlink returns:
None
```

Comment: This is how external links work. You'll probably need to update these.

Comment: If the cell contains `=Sheet1!A1` this is a `formula` not a `hyperlink` so there will be no `cell.hyperlink`, it's value will be `None`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense moken. Why is it that links in the formulas are being replaced with brackets with values inside? These links reference cell values in a different workbook located in a SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

I found the desired information, but further exploration is required. I need to dive deeper into the reason behind the substitution of links with brackets and values in the cell.value attribute.

Here is a useful code snippet for extracting external links from a workbook:

```
# Get external links list
items = workbook._external_links

# Iterate through list and extract url
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    Mystr = workbook._external_links[index].file_link.Target
    Mystr=Mystr.replace("file:///","")
    print(Mystr.replace("%20"," "))
```

I hope this helps.